# Compiling ClojureScript from cljc files with lein

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript, cljc

Does cljc / lein / clojurescript work yet?

I was previously using cljx, and was able to compile the same project with the cljx plugin for lein firing off a cljsbuild task.

Now I'm switching to cljc, I want to compile my cljc files into both compiled Java and into javascript for use in the browser.

Here's my current project.clj file

```
(defproject com.mysite/myproj "0.3.2-SNAPSHOT"
  :description ""
  :url ""
  :license {:name "Gnu Lesser Public License"
            :url "https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}    
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]]    
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.3"]
            [lein-localrepo "0.4.0"] ]    
  :source-paths ["cljc" "src" ]    
  :cljsbuild {:builds [{
                        :source-paths ["cljc"  ]
                        :compiler {
                                   :output-to "browser-based/js/main.js"
                                   :optimizations :whitespace
                                   :pretty-print true }
                        } ]}    
  :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]
  :aot [myproj.core]
  :main myproj.core)
```

I don't remember exactly where I copied some of this from, but I assume that the leiningen.cljsbuild hook was what automatically fired off the cljs build process. However after removing the cljx plugin, and moving to cljc, this is successfully compiling the Java version of my program but doesn't seem to be producing any javascript.

Comment: Can you post your directory tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works.

Try with:

```
(defproject com.mysite/myproj "0.3.2-SNAPSHOT"
  :description ""
  :url ""
  :license {:name "Gnu Lesser Public License"
            :url "https://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html"}    
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.28"]    
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.6"]
            [lein-localrepo "0.4.0"]]   
  :source-paths ["cljc" "src"]    
  :cljsbuild {:builds [{
                        :source-paths ["cljc" "src"]
                        :compiler {:output-to "browser-based/js/main.js"
                                   :optimizations :whitespace
                                   :pretty-print true}}]}    
  :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild])
```

Then run: `lein compile` or `lein cljsbuild once`

Please note that I changed the `:source-paths` under :cljsbuild to include "src": `:source-paths ["cljc" "src"]`. Apart from that I added an explicit dependency on clojurescript and bumped cljsbuild version to 1.0.6

By the way, why do you have a separate `cljc` directory? You can have your cljc, clj & cljs files sharing the same directory structure.

Comment: Please notice that `lein-doo` is meant for testing.

Comment: Oh, you are right @sbensu, I'll fix the answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Yes that works.

Re: cljc directory. Well, it's initially just a renaming of my cljx directory (and all cljcs are renamed cljxs). But I saw somewhere online someone using that layout.